# PHP url encoding problems

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have some URL which is in CP-1251 i believe. For example:

```
http://domain.com/Test - СЃСѓС‚СЊ РІ СЌС‚РѕРј.mp3
```

`mb_detect_encoding` says it is ASCII. However, I've tried to convert this to UTF-8, but no luck. However the following worked:

```
$url = mb_convert_encoding(urldecode($url), "Windows-1251", "auto");
```

Which means that it converted the url to `Windows-1251`. Which is strange, but it shows the characters right. But when I insert this converted url inside an html object (some music player) it doesn't work. Firebug shows an error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://domain.com/Test%20-%20????%20?%20????.mp3"
```

So somehow I got question marks instead of a right url. `urlencode` doesn't help.

The file itself is `utf-8`.

I'm confused with all this stuff. Is there any solution here?

Comment: Have you tried `utf8_encode($url)`? If your page has it's encoding set to utf-8, this should work.

Comment: @Michel Mior - yes I have. And it gives me the following: `http://domain.com/Test - Ð¡ÐÐ¡ÑÐ¡âÐ¡Ð Ð Ð Ð¡ÐÐ¡âÐ ÑÐ Ñ.mp3` which isn't good of course.

Comment: When you say "the file itself is `utf-8`" do you mean the HTML page?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter now, the problem is solved. Thanks for everybody here for your replies.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer for future readers?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post it as an answer. Stackoverflow has limitations for posting answers for your own questions. But I have already posted the answer after the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

**Just needed to take the file name separately and [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) it.**

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what answer you're looking for but its original encoding is Windows-1251, you can check with iconv:

```
var_dump(detect_encoding($url);

function detect_encoding($string) { 
  static $list = array('utf-8', 'windows-1251');

  foreach ($list as $item) {
    $sample = iconv($item, $item, $string);
    if (md5($sample) == md5($string))
      return $item;
  }
  return null;
}
```

This site can also be quite helpful: [Universal Cyrillic Decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en)